# Find and replace in Snowsight

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does the new Snowsight (preview app) interface provide functionality to find/replace text in the query pane?

In the current interface I can use **ctrl-F** and **ctrl-shift-f** for find and replace respectively. They don't seem to work in Snowsight. The search box in the Results pane only works with returned results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: This is not supported by Snowsight.

Meanwhile just search will work as expected from the browser.

Comment: It is possible to replace and even supports regexp though this feature is not easily discoverable.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to enable Replace functionality in Snowsight by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**[image: strong text]**

[image]

---

This and more features are discoverable under [Keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-query.html#keyboard-shortcuts):

> Snowsight also provides keyboard shortcuts for faster navigation and editing of worksheets. To view the list of supported keyboard shortcuts, press [CMD]+[SHIFT]+[?] (Mac) or [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[?] (Windows).

[image]

---

*EDIT*

New Find and Replace UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this question like me, now there's a way.
On Mac, hit CMD + Option + f.
Guess you can replace CMD w/ Ctrl and Option w/ Alt if your'e on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

On the upper right corner of the editing window there is a search icon that provides a 'replace' option.